# Bulk or batch POST/PATCH in API-Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

As far as I see in our **API-Platform** implementation, there is no way to POST (creation) or PATCH (update) several entities at the same time in the same call, by sending a json array of objects.

Am I missing something?
We have a custom DataItem Provider, that may be messing up the default POST collection operation?
It isn't clearly described in the generated Swagger/OpenAPI either that you may want to send an array instead of a single object.

Comment: This could be useful https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/294